# How to export describe/tests and reuse them in another test files in jest

Tags: node.js, import, jestjs, export

I have a test file that is too long and I want to divide it into several files when each file contains a test on a different domain.
In addition I want to create one file that can run all the tests from all the files
In the order I set for him.
How do I export describes from the small files and import them into the general file
Something like this:

gridTest.js:

```
export describe ("grid")
```

sanityTest.js:

```
import "grid" from "./gridTest"

grid ()
```

And so on ...

Comment: you might have to explore more concrete code on github.

Comment: Sharpens the question - how to use a ready-made describe in another file??This is such a useful thing - how can it be that there is no solution ??

Answer (score 4):

I used "require" function which causes the file to run.
For example:

gridTest.js

//write tests and describes

sanityTest.js

describe('grid', () => {

```
  //This will run the entire gridTest.js file
  require('./gridTest);
```

})

Comment: But what if I want to pass some variables to my test function? such as testing a different route?